# Calculating the expected value and variance of an estimator of a normal quantile

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, variance, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

I don't quite understand how to use the estimator function and the variance function and plug in the sample mean. I expected that we would plug in the value $\bar X - 1.645s$ into $E(s)$ and $V(s)$. This seemed like it would give us $c4 \times \sigma \times (\mu - 1.645)$, however this did not work for the second one as I expected it would be $(\sigma^2)/(2n) \times \ (\mu - 1.645)$. This was not the case, and now I'm not sure what it means to find the expected value and variance of the estimator.

[image: First Image]

[image: second Image]

Comment: I formatted the mathematical expressions in your question. Please ensure they're correct. There seems to be a $($ missing in the last expression. The included questions say that $c4$ "is a function of $n$", is there any more information given about what it is (perhaps in your lecture notes or somewhere)?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe it is just a general expression for a function of n.

Comment: @gung I expect they are referring to the quantity $c_4$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Unbiased_sample_standard_deviation)

Comment: Could you clarify the steps you went through to get the two answers you gave, rather than just the answers themselves? It would help in explaining exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: I explained how I came to the conclusion for how I got the answers that I thought were right in the first paragraph. The answers in red are the actual answers; they were given with no information on how to obtain them. I am trying to figure out how to get those answers

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply some basic rules for expectation and variance, and independence of $\bar X$ and $s$ under normal sampling.

[Basic properties of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties)

[Basic properties of variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties)

[Independence of mean and standard deviation in normal sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem#Sample_mean_and_sample_variance)

I think everything else is in the question. You could get more accurate results for variance than those in the answers by applying information about $c_4$ given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Unbiased_sample_standard_deviation).